# CLion does not paste the correct snippet from clipboard

Tags: clion

while having used Java and PHP most of the time in my programming "carreer", I am now trying to learn C++ more in-depth. For that, I am using CLion as my IDE - mostly because I am very familiar with phpStorm and IntelliJ IDEA and I don't want to "learn" a new IDE in addition to learning a new language.

Now, I have hit the problem, that CLion does not take my current Clipboard content when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>. The snippet was copied from the Browser (Firefox 41.0.1) and it neither works with code copied by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> nor with code copied by rightclicking and then selecting `Copy`.

It seems like the IDE has problems with getting the Clipboard content from the outside, because when copying and pasting inside the IDE, it works perfectly fine. Only when trying to paste something from another program, it ignores it and pastes something that I copied inside the IDE before.

Do you have any clues on how to fix that? Is it a bug or did I mess up something in my settings or somewhere else?

Comment: I have this issue as well and its driving me nuts.

Comment: Do you  work under the Windows OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Ctrl+V work in CLion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331304/how-to-make-ctrlv-work-in-clion)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearing "Paste from History" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) worked for me.

Comment: Does not work all the time, but I was able to confirm this workaround for most of the times, so I will mark your answer as accepted to show other users a possible fix :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with Chrome version `47.0.2526.106`.

It seems like that the problem happens when more then one Clion project window is open. After resetting the clion clipboard the problem will not occur during the session again. But after starting a new Clion session the bug is back in place.

Added on 27th december: It also happens when you are only working with one window and stored 5 values in the clion clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

For me works only using middle mouse button for paste.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This was the only way I could get text selected in an xterm into clion (middle button).

Answer (score 0):

There sometimes is a notification when you try to use several shortcuts that this is already taken by some VIM Commands and if you want to disable this. Selecting yes didn't change a thing for me.
But using that hint, going to File>Settings>Plugins, disabling IdeaVIM and than restarting did the job.

Fabrizios answered on the duplicate item something, that was partly helpful for me: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> brings up the clipboard history)
This still left me with the actual problem (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and more not working).