# How to make Ctrl+V work in CLion

Tags: clion

I am having difficulty getting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste code in *CLion* (I am using version 1.1.1 for Windows). When I try to paste code copied using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from e.g. a website or another program, it only seems to work occasionally. Usually it pastes a piece of text that was not the most recently copied.

I use other JetBrains IDEs (IntelliJ IDEA, PyCharm) and have never had any problems with something so basic.

Has anybody else encountered this problem and found a solution to it?

Comment: In my case, I've replaced my current version with the latest EAP and the problem went away.

Comment: Please look at my answer here:[CLion does not paste the correct snippet from clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47527213/3914914)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CLion does not paste the correct snippet from clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32989917/clion-does-not-paste-the-correct-snippet-from-clipboard)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem and this is the way I fixed it:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (brings up the clipboard history)
- Delete all entries
- Recopy what you wanted to paste from outside *CLion*
- Try pasting again

Let me know if it didn't work for you so I can see if there is some step you are missing. Hope this helps!

Comment: It seems to work, but it's hard to test properly, as the problems were so erratic in the first place. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Glad it helped! And yea, I'm sure there is a better way, but this is the only method I discovered.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid having to do this, aside from switching to an IDE other than CLion?

Comment: Also, they claim that this issue is fixed; I just experienced it, and it's not.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is the way I fixed it:
Go to: Settings > plugins  and disable 'ideaVim' plugin